# The text isn't displaying on expo app. I think the prop is not being passed properly. How should I correct that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

The component file:

```
{  return (
    <TouchableOpacity /* onLongPress={onLongPress} style={[styles.card, backgroundColor]} */>
      <View style={styles.fixToText}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.post_title}</Text>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name="star-outline"
          size={24}
          color="black"/>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.tasks}>{item.post_info}</Text>
        <View style={styles.fixToText}>
          <Text style={styles.time}>{item.time}</Text>
        </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

App.js file

```
const App = () => {

  const [tasks,setTasks]= useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      post_title: "NEW Task",
      post_info: "Assigned with the ID",
      time: "1 min ago",
    },
   {
      id: 2,
      post_title: "NEW Task",
      post_info: "Assigned with the ID",
      time: "1 min ago",
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <>
     <Notification task={tasks}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am sure that the props are not being properly passed. Where exactly is it wrong ? I have passed it from App to Component file using {task} . I can only see the star icon though displayed at the side.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to attach the whole component?

it seems like the name should be either props.task[i].post_title

or in case you destruct the props using const {task}=props it should be task[i].post_title

Comment: I don't get you. Like why do I need to pass each task when I can pass the whole data altogether?

Comment: In order for you to understand me better, i suggest that you attach the whole Notification component.

What i meant that, You are sending an Array of objects to your component. Thus, to react to one of the keys (id, post_title, etc..) you will have to either use map function over your array (props.task.map...) or just to reach the specific item in your array using 
props.task[i]....